# spring mvc binding/validation

Tags: java, spring-mvc

so lets say I have some model class:

```
public class MyRequestParams {
    private Long val = Long.valueOf(0); // default value

    // ... plus some other stuff
}
```

And what I want, is if the user provides http://host/path?val=& OR http://host/path?val=abc, which is invalid params, I don't want it to fail. I want it to just apply the default. I'm not sure how to do this at the moment except for storing val as a string and doing any checks to apply the default myself. Is there some easy way while keeping the type == Long?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested, but you could register a custom editor for your property, using [`registerCustomEditor`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/validation/DataBinder.html#registerCustomEditor%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String,%20java.beans.PropertyEditor%29), in a method annotated with [`@InitBinder`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/InitBinder.html). This editor would simply return the default long value.

See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html for documentation and examples.